# In SQL Server I am trying to count the days between a car rental drop off and a car rental pickup for a specific customer, car make, and date

Tags: sql, sql-server

[These are the data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdsP5.png)I have tried several different select statements to count the days between when the car was picked and when it should be dropped off. It should return a value of 4, however, I keep getting 1

```
select  count  (Date_Out) as TotalDays 
from Customer, rentals
where Customer.CID = Rentals.CID
and CName = 'Black'
and Make = 'GM'
and Date_out = '11/01/2009'
```

When I try to sum the Date_out and Date_returned it gives the error that you cannot sum the data type which is small date, I'm not sure what I am missing, but any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!

Comment: Please Add Your Data and Expected Result With  a better Sample

Comment: Please provide table definition and / or data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql Server one can use DATEDIFF to calculate the interval between DATE/TIME/DATETIME values.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, r.Date_Out, r.Date_Returned) as TotalDays 
FROM Customer c
JOIN Rentals r
ON r.CID = c.CID
AND c.CName = 'Black'
AND r.Make = 'GM'
AND CAST(r.Date_out AS DATE) = CAST('2019-11-01' AS DATE)
```

Comment: It returned the column heading in the resultset, but no data

Comment: @AmberNicoleChristensen-Thoma Is it because I changed that datestamp to the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format?  I did that because that's a common format where it's clear which is the month versus the day.